# Echo an image from the page in php without Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, echo, facebook-opengraph

I am using the following code to echo the fourth image from the page as an `og image tag`, however it uses the `Simple HTML DOM Parser`, which reads the page first then reloads an edited version, which in turn slows down loading of pages.  Is there a way to do the same (echo an `img` tag from the page) without using "Simple HTML DOM Parser" to reload the page?  With editing this script or using a new one (like regex, preg_match, getElementsByTagName.. etc).

I can use JavaScript to do that, but it will load client-side, and it is needed to load server-side while loading the page.

**The current php code:**

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $link="";

    $html = file_get_html('/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs' . 
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

    $link=$html->find('img')[3]->src;

    $ret = $html->find('meta[property="og:image"]');
    $ret[0] = new stdClass();
    //$ret1[0] = new stdClass();
    $ret[0]->content = $link;
?>

    <meta property="og:image" 
    content="https://example.com/<?php echo $ret[0]->content; ?>" />
```

**Example of html:**

```
<body>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p>
<img border="0" src="../path/to/file/image.jpg" width="1200" height="630"></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
<p>
<img border="0" src="../path/toanoter/file/imagetwo.jpg" width="1200" height="630"></p>
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p>
<img border="0" src="../path/to/file/image345.jpg" width="1200" height="630"></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
<p>
<img border="0" src="../../path/imagenew.jpg" width="1200" height="630"></p>
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
```

**Output should be:**

```
<meta property="og:image" 
content="https://example.com/path/imagenew.jpg" />
```

Comment: Wow, this is a real oldschool setup. Scraping the static content of one file into another. Let me ask, where does the file you scrape know the image from? Can't you just pick the image from a database, which would be much more reliable :-S

Comment: Hehe.. Yes, old school for an old site that needs a bit of modernising.. Database too might slow things down for static 150k+ pages (I just tread html as php through config file to add some php in the files).

Comment: I would look at using a regular expression instead of a DOM parser.

Comment: @zvineyard Thanks, can you suggest an edit to the script so I can test?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$pattern = '/src=\".+(\/path.+\.jpg)\"/m';
$html = 'your html page';

preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$siteUrl = 'https://example.com';
echo $siteUrl . $matches[3][1];
```

Comment: Thanks, but the page html is not in a variable `$html`, it's just and html page that is treated as php.

Comment: You can get it using file_get_contents

Comment: I tried adding `$html = file_get_html('/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs' .     $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` but it is not working.